# How to print a variable as defined in a method?

Tags: java, eclipse, scope

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int lastFibo = 1;  // ADDED TO check if last fib calculated is over 4000000
        for (int i = 3; lastFibo <= 4000000; i = i + (i - 1)) {
            lastFibo = fibo(i);
        }
    }

    public static int fibo(int i) {
        int total = 0;
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            total += i;
            return total;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

The purpose of this code is to print the sum of even numbers in the fibonacci sequence who's values are less than 4 million. Using recursion the code returns a stack overflow error so it was recommended to iterate through the numbers. The difficulty encountered was knowing how to print the "total" variable. Scope articles are very basic and creating a `static int total = 0` would `return 0`.

Comment: This isn't clear.  What's wrong with `System.out.println(total);` at the relevant point?

Comment: Are you saying that total is always return 0  instead of the true total?

Comment: The fib(4000000) has more than 835k digits.

Comment: I do not see any recursion here an I doubt that this code  generates a `StackOverflowException` (because of the missing recursion). Furthermore `i = i + (i - 1)` does not calculate any fibonacci-number. If you set `i` to `5`, you will get `9` as result, which is obviously no fibonacci-number.

Comment: Your code is wrong. From the code it is interpreted that you need to calculate Fibonacci values up to the 4.000.000 number.... when i = 40000000 you calculate Fibonacci(i). Correct it otherwise people can misunderstand

Comment: Explain exactly. You need to calculate up to Fibonacci(3999999) or up to Fibonacci(x) < 4000000 ?

Comment: I used recursion in another attempt and it recursed too deeply. @Turing85

Comment: @Houssam7111 the main problem is your `for` loop. As I demonstrated, the formula is simply wrong (let `i_0 = 5`, therefore `i_1 = 5 + 5 - 1 = 9`). Correct this formula.

Comment: I need to loop through all the numbers in the fibonacci sequence 1,2,3,5,8... until I reach 4000000, not the 4000000th term @DavideLorenzoMARINO

Comment: So please correct the code. It calculates fib(3), fib(4), fib(5), ... fib(4000000)

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO No, it does not calculate fibonacci-numbers right now. The actual "calculation" is done with the iteration-part within the `for` loop. `fibo(int i)` does only check, whether the parameter `i` is even. If it is, `fibo(int i)` returns `i`, otherwise it returns `0`.

Comment: int p = 1;
  for (int i = 3; i < 100; i = i + (i - p)) {
   p++;
   System.out.println(i);
  }
 }
Shouldn't this code print out fibonacci? It prints the numbers in order (1,2,3,4,5,...)yet I calculated that it would work. @Turing85

Comment: @Houssam7111 you answered your own question. If it does not print the fibonacci sequence, then there is a bug in this logic. I doubt that it will print `1` as its first value, since `i` is set to `3` and not changed before the 1st `System.out.println(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as pointed out by some comments: your for loop will not iterate the Fibonacci sequence. Second, the variable `total` exists only in the scope of your `fibo` method. So every time the method is called, `total` starts with the value `0`.

Use the correct Fibonacci algorithm and add the return value of the `fibo` method up to calculate the sum:

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int total = 0;
        int previousValue = 0;
        int currentValue = 1;
        while (currentValue < 4_000_000) {
            int nextPreviousValue = currentValue;
            currentValue += previousValue;
            previousValue = nextPreviousValue;
            total += fibo(currentValue);
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }

    public static int fibo(int i) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            return i;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

4_000_000 is an integer literal you can use since Java 7 for the number 4000000. The purpose of the underscores is to make it better readable for humans. Programmatically there is no difference to using 4000000. For details see [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) in The Java Tutorials.

Comment: It is not possible to handle so big Fibonacci number with primitive types!

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO before downvoting a question, get your facts straigth (see my comment on your answer).

Comment: I removed the downvote. The code of the question has bring me to the error, sorry. I am waiting to check if Housaim is asking for Fib(4000000) or fib(x) less than 4000000

Comment: *I need to loop through all the numbers in the fibonacci sequence 1,2,3,5,8... until I reach 4000000, not the 4000000th term @DavideLorenzoMARINO* (taken from OP).

Comment: This seems to be correct. However, it would be nice to explain some of the concepts you used (e.g. `4_000_000` and the use of `nextPreviousValue`) since OP seems to be a beginner in Java.

Comment: Many of the codes worked yet this is so simple! Simply brilliant! It translates exactly what the programmer is thinking into literal words!     @hzpz

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** This first part of the question was related to a misunderstanding. I supposed that it was necessary to calculated up to `fib(4000000)`.

*You must use `BigInteger` otherwise you can't handle so big numbers. It is a number with many thousands of digits!
fib(4000000) results in a number with over 835k digits. It is not possible to handle it with `int` or `long`. 
The class `BigInteger` (or the equivalent `BigDecimal` for decimal values) borns to handle such kind of problems.*

---

**Note:** this is the answer to the question

Now that the question is more clear it is possible to give the correct answer.

```
public void printEvenFib() {
    int i = 1;
    int lastFib = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    while (lastFib <= 4000000) {
        if (lastFib % 2 == 0) {
            sum += lastFib;
        }
        i++;
        lastFib = fib(i);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}

 // Without recursion
 public int fib(int n) {
     if (n <= 2) {
         return 1;
     }
     int fibo1 = 1;
     int fibo2 = 1;
     int fibo = 0;
     for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
         fibo = fibo1 + fibo2;
         fibo2 = fibo1;
         fibo1 = fibo;
     }
     return fibo;
 }
```

Comment: You missinterpreted the question. OP does not want to calculate the 4 000 000th fibonacci-number, but all fibonacci-numbers smaller than 4 000 000. Therefore, this is not an answer.

Comment: Before downvoting wait a better explain of the question

Comment: No. Before writing an answer, wait until the question is clear.

Comment: Error in line 19: `i` cannot be resolved to a variable (refers to the `if` within `public int fib(int n)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program2{
public static void main(String args[]){
     int n1=0,n2=1,n3,total=0,i;
     for(i=1;n3<4000000;++i){ 
        n3=n1+n2;
        if(n3%2==0)
            total+=n3;
        n1=n2;    
        n2=n3;    
    } 
    System.out.println("total is "+total);  
}
```

}